# How to access laravel api from vuejs frontend?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, cpanel

I have built a laravel api, I have placed the backend inside a laravel folder in the cpanel and the built vuejs frontend inside public_html, now u can see I am using both api.php and web.php, my frontend is working fine when I visit https://www.example.com but what's the url to my api endpoints since when I try something like https://www.example.com/api/somepage it doesn't work it just hits the routes I set using vue router?

Please I need help here I am a beginner,  and thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel apis have default [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware) to establish security. Make sure you send tokens. In my opinion, test it in postman first.

If you have a 404 error , [this link can help you](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-api-routes-404-not-found)

Sometimes it is possible that there is a problem with the route cache, so it is better to delete the route cache and create it again

```
php artisan route:clear 
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Locally everything is working fine I can access the endpoints and everything from the frontend with authentication and stuff ?